# Jenkins duplicate workspace directories?

Tags: jenkins

Working with Jenkins, I'm looking into cleaning up unused workspaces, as to save space on disk.

I noticed something strange though: projects would be copied several times, only with slightly different directory names.

Example:

```
workspaces
   project1
   project1@tmp
   project1@2
   project1@2@tmp
```

Is this normal? Are these 3 extra directories safe to clean?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it would be safe to delete those. Though I would suggest you do the delete/clean up as part of your pipeline job, maybe as the last step? (drop the workspace) rather doing it manually yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Are there further consequences to dropping a workspace? For instance, will I still be able to access old build and branches?

Comment: The old builds have no relation to the workspace. So yes you will be able to access those. the housekeeping of old builds is usually done by plugins like discard old build. https://plugins.jenkins.io/discard-old-build/